# Solving quartic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quartics

Given the following quartic equation:

$$x^4-2x^3-7x^2+8x+12=0$$

Could anyone give some techniques required to solve any quartic equation (apart from this one) if they exist?

Comment: See [quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: you should accept any one answer if your query has been answered ...if not you can ask for more information or clear your confusions by adding a comment below any answer...

Answer (score 9):

Are you familiar with the rational roots theorem? It says that any rational roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients must have the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ is a factor of the polynomial's constant term and $q$ is a factor of its leading term.

The constant term of your polynomial is $12$ and its leading term is $1$, so the possibilities for rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 4, \pm 6$, and $\pm 12$. Note that these are only *possibilities*. You have to test them to see if they work. If you test all the possibilities, you'll find that there are four which work ($-1, 2, -2$, and $3$). Since any quartic polynomial has at most four real roots, you can be sure that you've found all of them.

Unfortunately, many quartic polynomials have roots which are not rational. For example, suppose that you can only find two roots $a$ and $b$ using the rational roots theorem. You could then divide the polynomial by the factor $x - a$ and then again by the factor $x-b$ to produce a quadratic equation (you can do this because of the remainder theorem, mentioned in another answer). Then use the quadratic formula to find the remaining roots.

So, basically, this technique is only useful when your polynomial has at least two rational roots.

There are techniques for solving *any* quartic equation, but they are quite advanced. You don't see them until you study field theory in depth. You might encounter the topic as an advanced undergraduate, but even then I think it's usually skipped.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $x = 2$ is a root. Can you take it from here? in general, there are some tricks out there, for example if you have the type I: $x^4+ ax^3+ bx^2+ ax + 1 = 0$, then you divide both sides by the middle $x^2$ and put $y = x+\dfrac{1}{x}$, reducing it to a quadratic equation immediately.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, could you please share some more tricks if possible?

Answer (score 2):

As an A level student, I would first look at this with the Remainder Theorem, which states that if we sub in a value, say 1, and we get zero, then (x-1) is a factor.

Let $$p(x)=x^4-2x^3-7x^2+8x+12$$
Sub in -1:
$$p(-1)=(-1)^4-2(-1)^3-7(-1)^2+8(-1)+12 = 0$$
Therefore, (x + 1) must be a factor. We can then use algebraic division to gain a cubic equation. After doing the division, we are left with:
$$p(x)=(x+1)(x^3-3x^2-4x+12)$$
We can then use the remainder theorem to try and factorise the cubic. Subbing in -2, we get another 0. Therefore, (x+2) is a factor of the cubic. Long division gives that p(x) equals:
$$p(x)=(x+1)((x+2)(x^2-5x+6))$$
The quadratic can be factorised to give:
$$p(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x-3)(x-2)$$
Since this equals 0, then:
$$x+1 = 0 \implies x = -1$$
$$x+2 = 0 \implies x = -2$$
$$x-3 = 0 \implies x = 3$$
$$x-2 = 0 \implies x = 2$$
To confirm, a graph gives:

[image: graph]

Comment: So letting $x=z+1/2$ gives $$z^4-\frac{17}{2}z^2+\frac{225}{16}=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

For reference and examples on Quartic equations check out this site: [The Quartic Formula](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html)

---

To solve a quartic equation Ludovico Ferrari used a very similar method as for the cubic equation.([The Cubic Formula](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html))

---

**I.** The first objective is to find two roots of equation (1). Once we have them the other two roots (real or complex) can be found by polynomial division and the quadratic formula.

---

[image: 1]

---

**II.** To find the two roots we use a substitution:

---

[image: 2]

to the quartic equation (1) to obtain:

---

[image: 3]

Multiplying out and simplifying, we obtain the "depressed" quartic (no cubed term)

---

[image: 4]

---

For example:

[image: 5]
[image: 6]

---

**III.** Solving the depressed quartic.

[image: 7]

---

We will first move the y-term to the other side:

[image: 8]

---

Next, we "complete the square" on the left side, but we want to end up with

[image: 9]

To accomplish that, we add the term:

---

[image: 10]

on both sides:

---

[image: 11]

---

Simplifying the left side results in

[image: 12]

---

Now we use a new unknown z, we want to change the left side of (5) to

[image: 13]

---

which means to add :
[image: 14]

To both sides of (5) to obtain:

---

[image: 15]

The left side is a "perfect square". The next step will be to determine z so that the right side looks like a perfect square as well. For that one needs to compute the determinant of the RHS. If the determinant is 0 we have a repeated root, which means a we have a perfect square. With this we get a value for z and the rest of the solution is plugging it back to our final equation and solve the quadratic. The other two roots can be found by polynomial long division, and application of the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$x^4-2x^3-7x^2+8x+12=0$$ substituting $x=-1$ we get $$(-1)^4-2(-1)^3-7(-1)^2+8(-1)+12=0\iff 0=0$$ Hence, $x=-1$ is a root of given quartic equation i.e. $(x+1)$ is a factor of $x^4-2x^3-7x^2+8x+12$, now we have 
$$(x+1)(x^3-3x^2-4x+12)=0$$
further factorizing $x^3-3x^2-4x+12=(x-3)(x^2-4)$
$$(x+1)(x-3)(x^2-4)=0$$ 
$$(x+1)(x-3)(x-2)(x+2)=0$$

Hence, the roots are  $$x=\color{red}{-2, -1, 2, 3}$$

Comment: "substituting x=−1 .." <-- may i know can we see that coming from the equation ?

Answer (score 1):

***Solving the linear, quadratic, cubic and quartic equations (how to reconstruct the solution for them - step by step, for easy memorization):***

We make use of the following accepted statements:

- According to the *Fundamental Theorem of Algebra*: An $n$'th degree polynomial equation ($n\neq0$) has exactly $n$ solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.
- If the equation has one complex number as a solution then it also has the complex conjugate of that number as a solution.
- If $n$ is odd, then the equation has at least $1$ real solution.

**A. Solving the linear equation (also called the first degree polynomial equation):**

Let $a$, $b$ be known real/complex coefficients, and $x$ - the unknown for the linear equation:

$ax + b = 0 \tag{1}$

*A.1. if $a=0$, then the equation (1) has:*

- an infinite number of solutions if $b=0$: $x\in \mathbb{R}$
- no solution if $b\ne0$: $x\in\emptyset$

*A.2. if $a\neq0$, then the equation (1) has:*

- one solution: $x_1=-b/a$

**B. Solving the quadratic equation (also called the second degree polynomial equation):**

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be known real/complex coefficients, and $x$ - the unknown for the quadratic equation:

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \tag{2}$

*B.1. if $a=0$, then the equation (2) reduces to a linear equation (see A.)*

*B.2. if $a\neq0$, then:*

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0 / \div a \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow x^2 + \frac{b}{a} \cdot x + \frac{c}{a} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

Now we try to complete the square (we use the identity $\left(A + B\right)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2)$:

$\Leftrightarrow \left( x^2 + 2 \cdot \frac{b}{2a} \cdot x + \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 \right) + \frac{4a \times c}{4a \times a} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow (x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 + \frac{4ac}{4a^2}  - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow$
\begin{equation}
\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2} = 0 \tag{3}
\end{equation}

$$\text{(the depressed form of the quadratic equation) } \Leftrightarrow$$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 = \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}$

Let $\Delta=\left(b^2 - 4ac\right) =$ the discriminant of $2$'nd degree equation.

$\Leftrightarrow |x + \frac{b}{2a}| = \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{|2a|} \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow x + \frac{b}{2a} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow x = -\frac{b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$

**C. Solving the cubic equation (also called the third degree polynomial equation):**

Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be known real/complex coefficients, and $x$ - the unknown for the cubic equation:

\begin{equation} 
ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0 \tag{4}
\end{equation}

*C.1. if a=0, then the equation (4) reduces to a quadratic equation equation (see B.)*

*C.2. if $a\ne0$, then:*

$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0 / \div a \Leftrightarrow$

$x^3 + \frac{b}{a}x^2 + \frac{c}{a}x + \frac{d}{a} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

Let $a_1=\frac{b}{a}$, $b_1=\frac{c}{a}$ and $c_1=\frac{d}{a}$:

$\Rightarrow$

(4) $\Leftrightarrow x^3 + b_1 \cdot x^2 + c_1 \cdot x + d_1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow$
Now we try to complete the cube for $x^3$ and $x^2$ (we use the identity $\left(A + B\right)^3 = A^3 + 3A^2B + 3AB^2 + B^3)$:

$\Leftrightarrow \left(x^3 + 3x^2\frac{b_1}{3} + 3x\left(\frac{b_1}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b_1}{3}\right)^3 \right) + c_1 \cdot x + d_1 - 3x\left(\frac{b_1}{3}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{b_1}{3}\right)^3 = 0\Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{b_1}{3}\right)^3 + \left(c_1 - \frac{b_1^2}{3}\right) \cdot x + d_1 - \left(\frac{b_1}{3}\right)^3 = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{b_1}{3}\right)^3 + \left(c_1 - \frac{b_1^2}{3}\right) \cdot \left(x + \frac{b_1}{3}\right) + \left(d_1 - \left(\frac{b_1}{3}\right)^3 - \left(c_1 - \frac{b_1^2}{3}\right) \cdot \frac{b_1}{3}\right) = 0 \tag{5}
\end{equation}
$\Leftrightarrow$

Let:
$y = \left(x + \frac{b_1}{3}\right)$

$c_2 = \left(c_1 - \frac{b_1^2}{3}\right)$

$d_2 = \left(d_1 - \left(\frac{b_1}{3}\right)^3 - \left(c_1 - \frac{b_1^2}{3}\right) \cdot \frac{b_1}{3}\right)$

\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow (5) \Leftrightarrow y^3 + c_2 \cdot y + d_2 = 0 \tag{6}
\end{equation}
$$\text{(the depressed form of the cubic equation) }$$

Now, we use the identity: $\left(A + B\right)^3 = A^3 + 3AB\left(A + B\right) + B^3 \Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \left(A + B\right)^3 - 3AB\left(A + B\right) - \left(A^3 + B^3\right) = 0 \tag{7}
\end{equation}

$(6) + (7) \Rightarrow$ Let A and B be two numbers, so that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c|c}
& y = \left(A + B\right) \\
& -3AB = c_2 \\
& and \\
& -\left(A^3 + B^3\right) = d_2 \\
\end{array} (8)
\end{equation}

If we can find $A$ and $B$ that match (8): then $y=A+B$ is a solution of the equation (6). Let us now find $A$ and $B$ that match these requirements:

(8) $\Rightarrow$

\begin{equation*}
  \Rightarrow\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      & 3AB = -c_2 \\
      & A^3 + B^3 = -d_2 \\
    \end{aligned}
  \right.\Leftrightarrow
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \Leftrightarrow\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      & B = -\frac{c_2}{3A} & (9) \\
      & A^3 + B^3 + d_2 = 0 & (10) \\
    \end{aligned}
  \right.\Leftrightarrow
\end{equation*}

We replace $B$ from $(10)$ with $(9)$:

$\Rightarrow A^3 - \left(\frac{c_2}{3A}\right)^3 + d_2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow A^3 - \frac{c_2^3}{27A^3} + d_2 = 0 / \cdot A^3 \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow A^6 - \frac{c_2^3}{27} + d_2 \cdot A^3 = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow A^6 + A^3 \cdot \left(d_2\right) - \frac{c_2^3}{27} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \left(A^3\right)^2 + d_2 \cdot A^3 - \frac{c_2^3}{27} = 0 \tag{11}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \text{Let }z=A^3 \tag{12}\end{equation}
$(11)$ + $(12)$ $\Leftrightarrow$
\begin{equation}
z^2 + d_2 \cdot z - \frac{c_2^3}{27} = 0 \tag{13}
\end{equation}

$\text{which is a quadratic equation with the unknown $z$, having two solutions $z_1$ and $z_2$ (see B.)} \tag{14}$

For each of the two $z$ ($z_1$ and $z_2$): there are $3$ possible complex solutions for $A$ (due to the cubic root of $z$):

$(14)$ + $(12)$ $\Leftrightarrow A_{1,2,3,4,5,6} = \sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}} \text{ [ + (9) ]} \Rightarrow B = -\frac{c_2}{3A_{1,2,3,4,5,6}} = -\frac{c_2}{3\sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}}} \text{ [ + (8) ]} \Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow y_{1,2,3,4,5,6} = A + B = \sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}} - \frac{c_2}{3\sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}}}$

Note: By calculus it can be obtained that three of the solutions are duplicate so there are only three solutions to the cubic equation (for further references see:
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Derivation_of_the_roots) and [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)):

$x + \frac{b_1}{3} = y = \sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}} - \frac{c_2}{3\sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}}}$
$\Rightarrow x_{1,2,3} = \sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}} - \frac{c_2}{3\sqrt[3]{z_{1,2}}} - \frac{b_1}{3}$

**D. Solving the quartic equation (also called the fourth degree polynomial equation):**

Let $a, b, c, d, e$ be known real/complex coefficients, and $x$ - the unknown for the quartic equation:

\begin{equation}
ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0 \tag{15}
\end{equation}

*D.1. if $a=0$, then the equation (15) reduces to a cubic equation (see C.)*

*D.2. if $a\neq0$, then:*

$ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0 / \div a \Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow x^4 + \frac{b}{a}\cdot x^3 + \frac{c}{a} \cdot x^2 + \frac{d}{a} \cdot x + \frac{e}{a} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

Let $b_1=\frac{b}{a}$, $c_1=\frac{c}{a}$, $d_1=\frac{d}{a}$ and $e_1=\frac{e}{a}$:

$\Rightarrow (15) \Leftrightarrow x^4 + b_1 \cdot x^3 + c_1 \cdot x^2 + d_1 \cdot x + e_1 = 0$

Now we try to complete the $4$th power of sum for $x^4$ and $x^3$ (we use the identity $\left(A + B\right)^4 = A^4 + 4A^3B + 6A^2B^2 + 4AB^3 + B^4$):

$\Leftrightarrow \left( x^4 + 4x^3\left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right) + 6x^2\left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^2 + 4x\left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 \right) + c_1 \cdot x^2 + d_1 \cdot x + e_1 - 6x^2\left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^2 - 4x\left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^3 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 + \left(c_1 - 3 \cdot \frac{b_1}{8}\right)x^2 + \left(d_1 - \frac{b_1^3}{16}\right) x + \left(e_1 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4\right) = 0 \tag{16} \end{equation} $\Leftrightarrow$

Now, we complete the square for $x^2$ in (16) (we use the identity $\left(A + B\right)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$):

$\Leftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 + \left(c_1 - 3 \cdot \frac{b_1}{8}\right)\left(x^2 + 2 \cdot \frac{b_1}{4} \cdot x + \left( \frac{b_1}{4}\right)^2\right) + \left(d_1 - \frac{b_1^3}{16} - 2 \cdot \frac{b_1}{4}\right) x + \left(e_1 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^2 \right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow $

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 + \left(c_1 - 3 \cdot \frac{b_1}{8}\right)\left(x + \frac{b_1}{4} \right)^2 + \left(d_1 - \frac{b_1^3}{16} - 2 \cdot \frac{b_1}{4}\right) \left(x + \frac{b_1}{4} \right) + \left(e_1 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^2 - \frac{b_1}{4}\left(d_1 - \frac{b_1^3}{16} - 2 \cdot \frac{b_1}{4}\right)\right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \tag{17}
\end{equation}

Let:
\begin{align*}
& y = x + \frac{b_1}{4} \\
& c_2 = \left(c_1 - 3 \cdot \frac{b_1}{8}\right) \\
& d_2 = \left(d_1 - \frac{b_1^3}{16} - 2 \cdot \frac{b_1}{4}\right) \\
& e_2 = \left(e_1 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^4 - \left(\frac{b_1}{4}\right)^2 - \frac{b_1}{4}\left(d_1 - \frac{b_1^3}{16} - 2 \cdot \frac{b_1}{4}\right)\right) \\
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow (17) \Leftrightarrow y^4 + c_2 \cdot y^2 + d_2 \cdot y + e_2 = 0
\tag{18} \end{equation}
$$ \text{(the depressed form of the quartic equation)} $$

We notice, that, in this form we have the $4$th, $2$nd and $1$st powers of $y$ (the $3$rd power of y is missing). This leads us to that we might be able to exploit the "square of the sum" by squaring the sum of $y^2$ and an extra variable ($u$) - we now use the identity:

\begin{equation}
\left(y^2 + u\right)^2 = y^4 + 2uy^2 + u^2 \tag{19}
\end{equation}

$\rightarrow$ notice that, in this identity we have $2$nd and $4$th powers of $y$

The equation (18) can be rewritten as:

\begin{equation}
y^4 = -c_2 \cdot y^2 - d_2 \cdot y - e_2 \tag{20}
\end{equation}

(19) + (20) $\Rightarrow$ \begin{equation}
(20) \Leftrightarrow \left(y^2 + u\right)^2 = \left(-c_2 \cdot y^2 - d_2 \cdot y - e_2\right) + 2uy^2 + u^2 \tag{21}
\end{equation}

(21) $\Leftrightarrow$ \begin{equation}
\left(y^2 + u\right)^2 = \left(2u - c_2\right)y^2 - d_2 \cdot y + u^2-e_2 \tag{22}
\end{equation}

We now try to bring the square of a linear function in $y$ in the right term of the equality:

(22) $\Leftrightarrow \left(y^2 + u\right)^2 = \left(\left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot y\right)^2 - 2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot y \cdot \frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}} + \left(\frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2 + u^2-e_2 - \left(\frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \left(y^2 + u\right)^2 = \left(\left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot y - \frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2 + u^2 - e_2 - \frac{d_2^2}{4 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)} \tag{23}
\end{equation}

We can now choose $u$, such that the right term of the equality becomes a square:

Let $u$, be a number such that:

\begin{equation}
u^2 - e_2 - \frac{d_2^2}{4 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \tag{24}
\end{equation}

$\Leftrightarrow \left(u^2 - e_2\right)\left(2u - c_2\right) - \frac{d_2^2}{4} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow 2u^3 - c_2 \cdot u^2 - 2 \cdot e_2 \cdot u + e_2 \cdot c_2 - \frac{d_2^2}{4} = 0 \tag{25}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{(25) is a cubic equation in u, having the solutions: $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ (see C.)} \tag{26}
\end{equation}

(23), (24), (26) $\Rightarrow$ (23) $\Leftrightarrow \left(y^2 + u\right)^2 = \left(\left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot y - \frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2 \Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \left(y^2 + u\right)^2 - \left(\left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot y - \frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2 = 0 \tag{27}
\end{equation}

We now use the identity: $(A^2 - B^2) = (A + B)(A - B)$:

$\Rightarrow$ (27) $\Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation*}
  \Rightarrow\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
  & y^2 + \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot y + u - \frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}} = 0 & (28) \\
  & OR & \notag \\
  & y^2 - \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot y + u + \frac{d_2}{2 \cdot \left(2u - c_2\right)^\frac{1}{2}} = 0 & (29) \\
    \end{aligned}
  \right.\Leftrightarrow
\end{equation*}

(28) and (29) are quadratic equations in $y$, having the solutions: $y_1$ and $y_2$, respectively $y_3$ and $y_4$ (see B.)

Using another $u$ from among the three roots of the cubic equation (25) simply causes these same four values for $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$ and $y_4$ in a different order.
$y_{1,2,3,4}=x_{1,2,3,4} + \frac{b_1}{4} \Rightarrow x_{1,2,3,4} = y_{1,2,3,4} - \frac{b_1}{4}$