# Solving a quartic equation.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Given a quartic equation:

$$x^4-5x^3-4x^2-2017x+4=0$$

If no help should be obtained from calculators and computers, can the roots be found?
If not, what is the nature of the roots? (Real, complex, positive, negative, zero, etc.)

It seems like by rational root theorem, this quartic equation does not have a rational root, but that's all I can manage, Vieta's doesn't help much for me either. 
(An elementary solution is very much preferred due to this being a secondary school contest problem)

Extra note: The original problem asked how many negative roots does the polynomial have. Thank you to whoever who reminded me about the unoriginality of the problem.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+-+5x%5E3+-+4x%5E2+-+2017x+%2B+4+%3D+0

Comment: do you need a symbolic solution?

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for the general formula.

Comment: Forget to mention, the problem appeared in a mathematics contest for secondary schools (referred to high schools sometimes), an elementary solution is very much preferred.

Comment: For solving a general quartic polynomial [this might be helpful](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function).

Comment: @MathEnthusiast If is was for secondary school, then *most probably* there is a *typo*. The correct equation has a rational root, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436053/solving-quartic-equations?rq=1).

Comment: Since the polynomial is monic, and the constant term is $4$, if there are any rational solutions they are among $\pm 1,\pm2,\pm4$ (the divisors of $4$). Other than that, there is no systematic way to check polynomials for elegant roots.

Comment: @hardmath I know. But you can just use wolframalpha to check that the solution isn't nice.

Comment: @MathEnthusiast put your comment about the need for an elementary solution, in the body of the question, pls.

Comment: The roots can't be found by hand (at least it's extremely unlikely for a high school student), the nature of roots can be found, one can notice the $2$ real and $2$ complex solutions.

Comment: Do you actually have the contest problem sheet? I suspect that they asked for the number of real roots, not the actual roots.

Comment: Law of signs as per the edit.

Comment: Since everyone here is telling you that the problem, as stated, is out of range for the type of contest you describe, then it should be obvious that either you stated the problem incorrectly, or the problem itself is wrong.

Comment: @quasi thank you for reminding

Comment: Ok, sorry -- _nature_ of the roots is an acceptable question.

Comment: If one takes upon @kingW3's comment and note that the two real roots must be positive, seeing as $f(0)>0>f(1)$, and $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, one can conclude no negative roots.

Comment: Here's the law of signs I mentioned earlier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Negative_roots

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears Descartes' method says the amount of negative roots is either 2 or 0, but it doesn't tell us which.

Comment: Based on @kingW3's comment, yes I can determine that there are 2 positive roots easily upon noticing that $f(0)>0>f(1)$, so the remaining 2 complex roots should be determined by knowing the quartic function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to see that there are no negative roots, when $x<0$ the only negative term in $x^4-5x^3-4x^2-2017x+4$ is $-4x^2$ so for it to be $0$ it must be $$-4x^2+4<0,-4x^2-2017x<0,-4x^2+x^4<0$$
But those $3$ inequalities aren't satisfied for any negative $x$.

SIDE NOTE: One should probably use $\leq$ instead of $<$ however the edge cases clearly don't satisfy the inequalities either.

Answer (score 0):

This quartic equation has no nice solution, which could be derived in a mathematics contest for secondary schools. The coefficient $2017$ seems to indicate it was from this year. Then the constant term is perhaps meant to be $-2019$, because then
$$
x^4-5x^3-4x^2-2017x-2019
$$
has a rational root. Furthermore it is easy then to see that there is exactly one negative root, namely $x=-1$. And it would be a nice contest question for in two years.

Answer (score 0):

suppose that the quartic has at least one negative root, $-a, a>0$.
$a^4+5a^3−4a^2+2017a+4=0$
$(a^2-2)^2+5a^3+2017a>0$ , contradiction
so no negative roots