# Solving a quartic equation without graphing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quartics

I'm currently working on a solution to a projectile motion problem, and I need to figure out the optimal launch angles by solving this system of equations.

$15\cos(\theta)x+2\cos(\theta)=21 \\\\
(15\sin(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}9.81x)x+2\sin(\theta)+3=0$

The first equation models the horizontal position of the projectile (which must be $21$ meters to the right in order to hit the target), and the second equation models the projectile's vertical height (which must be $0$ meters from the ground in order to hit the target). My goal was to solve for $x$ (time in seconds), and then plug those values into the original system to solve for $\theta$ (launch angle in degrees). After doing some simplification and substitution, I ended up with this equation:

$24.059025x^4-254.43x^2-60x+446=0$

I know that one approach to solving for $x$ would be to graph the function to see its zeroes. However, is it possible to solve this without graphing it?

Comment: There is always the [quartic formula](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/auckly29.pdf).

Comment: There's a [quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), but it's ugly. You might be better-off just using a [numerical method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms).

Comment: This is a physics problem, all you care about is approximations anyway. I would just use numerical methods.

Comment: There are many questions asking about how to solve a quartic. Just as an example, start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429309/solving-a-quartic-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703697/can-someone-help-me-solve-this-quartic-equation). With a computer algebra system, you just ask "solve".

Comment: [https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.11.E16](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.11.E16)